# SQL conditional constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, schema

I'm working on a database schema in PostgreSQL and want to implement the following system. I'm not sure how to implement the managers portion of it though. This isn't for a college assignment.

### Store a list of projects:

- Projects must be unique
- There can be zero or more projects

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

### Store a list of teams:

- Teams must be unique
- There can be zero or more teams

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

### Store a list of workers

- Workers must be unique
- There can be zero or more workers
- A worker must belong to one and only one team

```
CREATE TABLE workers (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    team_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES teams(id) NOT NULL
);
```

### Assign workers to projects

- The worker must exist
- The project must exist
- A worker can be assigned to many projects
- A project can have many workers
- A worker cannot be assigned to the same project more than once

```
CREATE TABLE worker_project (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    worker_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES teams(id) NOT NULL,
    project_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES projects(id) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (worker_id, project_id)
);
```

### Nominate a worker on a project to be a manager

- The worker must exist
- The project must exist
- The worker must be assigned to the project
- There can only be one manager from each team

This is the part I'm not sure about. I've tried amending the `worker_project` junction table with a boolean column `is_manager` and enforcing the constraints in code when it's mutated. But I'd like to have the constraint within the schema itself.

```
CREATE TABLE worker_project (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    worker_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES teams(id) NOT NULL,
    project_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES projects(id) NOT NULL,
    is_manager BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (worker_id, project_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a trigger ([Learn](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_triggers.htm)) that executes on insert/update of the record to ensure that only one record has is_manager = 1 for any specific project id.

Comment: [Such triggers are susceptible to race conditions.](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/)